# Odd Xcode issue with compiler errors on release scheme with older Mac OS project

Tags: xcode, macos, properties

I have a project that was released under 10.6. It has fairly standard "debug" and "release" schemes.

I'm doing some new work on it for a client that wants a custom version. I'm using Xcode 4.5.1, and have the base SDK set to 10.7, but the deployment target set to 10.6 for backwards compatibility.

In the new code I've written I've started using the auto-generated instance variables that were added to Xcode recently (not sure if this was 4.4 or 4.5). I sometimes use the _iVar variable inside a class' implementation to access the underlying iVar for a property.

My debug scheme builds a debug version of the clinet just fine.

However, when I switch to the release scheme, ever reference to an auto-generated instance variable throws an undeclared identifier error.

There must be some setting that is correct in my debug scheme but not in my release scheme. I am not an expert on build settings, and don't know what that setting would be. Can somebody help me?

I also have another problem that puzzles me. I added a new class to my project (which is maintained in a remote SVN repository.) The new files were marked with an "A" in the project navigator, indicating that they were flagged to be added to my repo on the next commit.

I decided to rename the class. I've had problems in the past with renaming files that are under source control, so what I did was to duplicate the files in the finder, change their names to the new names, and add them to the project. I then deleted the OLD files from the project in Xcode. Now, however, when I build, I  get a warning that these old files are missing. Somewhere Xcode still has a reference to the files that I told it to delete. Where would those references be, and how do I remove them? My "Compile sources" build phase for the project shows the new files, but not the old files that I deleted.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Duncan Champney
WareTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to the first part of my question, and it's not good.

The issue is that on Mac OS, Objective C 2.0 requires the modern Objective C runtime. THAT requires 64 bit.

On iOS, the modern Objective C runtime is available for all OS versions, and Objective C 2.0 is available for several recent iOS versions.

On Mac OS, the only version of the OS that is 64-bit only is 10.8. It's my understanding that OS 10.6 and 10.7 installation defaults to 32 bit.

In order to use Objective C 2.0 features, we have to build 64-bit only, which means that people running their machines in 32 bit mode can't use our app. That's bad.